# When did Jack Sparrow get the cheek/jaw scar?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean

Look carefully on Jack's jaw in these pictures, especially the left side of the picture. Under the 4th eye, to the left from his moustache there is a red ellipse. The picture is from the *Dead Man's Chest* (found [here](http://www.jacksparrowcostuming.com/images/SpiderBugFaceMakeupRefPic.jpg)).

[image: Jack with the eye makeup on his face]

Now look at this picture (found [here](https://ttcritic.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/pirates_of_the_caribbean_015.jpg)) from *The Curse of the Black Pearl* and see the difference between the pictures.

[image: Jack and Will escaping on a ship]

Any ideas when he got the scar? I don't think it's a scar from a fight as it looks fresh even in the latest movie (*Dead Men Tell no Tales*/*Salazar's Revenge*). It looks like the skin was ripped off in some strange way. Similar to the look of a wound after a fat/pus surgery.

Also, it's just the character's scar, not Johnny's. See this [calendar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/161701477X) for reference.

Comment: FWIW [looking closely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWOLl.jpg) at the second image it does look like the scar is there, it's just that it is hidden in the shadow and hair so is hard to see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He actually does have the scar in *The Black Pearl*. It can be seen in this YouTube clip, when Jack is about to be hanged at the end of the movie. You can see it at about 16 seconds in to the video

Here is a still from the scene, albeit a little blurry, it definitely shows a small red scar on his right jawline.

[image: Jack about to be hanged]

People have speculated this is from Syphilis, and Johnny Depp himself apparently has said it (although I can't find a reputable source for that).

Comment: Nice one. After I saw this answer I even looked up some make up videos of Depp but unfortunately I didn't find any mention about Syphilis or anything. As apparently no one has any better answer (or source or anything) have an accept too :)